# Which is better of these two class diagrams for calculator project and why?

Tags: java, c#, object-oriented, uml

I'm a novice programmer i draw two class diagrams for calculator Project, i want you to check each one of them and tell me which one is better and also, i would appreciate it if you point out the parts that are wrong or could be better.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why even have different classes for different operations, instead of just instances of the same class? Something like `new BinaryOperator("*", (x, y) => x * y)`

Comment: @CodesInChaos,in my opinion,if you want to add a new operator such as %, you dont need to modify source code of calculator. Just add a new file moduloExpr.cs

Comment: I suggest you start with a more high-level design, for example, the rough scetch of the data flow (involving the steps parsing / tokenization,  expression evaluation, user input/output). Then you think about the data objects which shall be the input to each step, and which are the output. **After that** you create the classes which fit to that model - the class model is good when it supports your high level design. Without knowing that design, your question is pointless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets start from the top. We want a `Calculator` that can take an input string and turn it into an Abstract Syntax Tree of expressions. I won't go into any specifics on lexing/parsing, but I can conclude that the Composite pattern is a good fit for this.

For the Composite pattern we start by defining an `Expression` interface that is a bit more general than yours;

```
interface Expression {
    double evaluate();
}
```

The idea of the Composite pattern is that any `Expression` can hold more `Expression` objects. This allows the lexer/parser to build an AST of expressions with a single root expression. Example:

```
// Don't mind the shorthand notation for brevity
Expression expr = constructAst("4 + 2 * 5") // AddExpr(4, MultExpr(2, 5));

// Evalutes 2 * 5 and then 4 + that result
expr.evaluate();
```

Now to allow for nesting of multiple expressions, the `BinaryExpression` needs to hold two expressions, instead of operating on two doubles:

```
abstract class BinaryExpression implements Expression {
    private Expression left;
    private Expression right;

    public BinaryExpression(Expression left, Expression right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public double evaluate() {
        evaluate(left.evaluate(), right.evaluate());
    }

    abstract protected double evaluate(double left, double right);
}
```

This approach does however require you to define expressions for numbers:

```
class NumberExpression implements Expression {
    private double number;

    public NumberExpression(double number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public double evaluate() {
        return (double) number;
    }
}
```

In your parser, you can cast integers to double to reuse the `NumberExpression`.

You can then easily define new binary expressions like so:

```
class AdditionExpression extends BinaryExpression {
    protected double evaluate(double left, double right) {
        return left + right;
    }
}
```

However, you can now also define a number of other expressions as you see fit:

```
class LogarithmExpression implements Expression [
    private Expression operand;

    public LogarithmExpression(Expression operand) {
        this.operand = operand;
    }

    public double evaluate() {
        return Math.log(operand.evaluate());
    }
}

class NegateExpression implements Expression {
    private Expression operand;

    public NegateExpression(Expression operand) {
        this.operand = operand;
    }

    public double evaluate() {
        return -operand.evaluate();
    }
}
```

Skipping the complex implementation details of the lexer/parser, your Calculator can now look like this:

```
class Calculator {
    public double calculate(string expression) {
        calculate(parseExpressionToAST(expression));
    }

    public double calculate(Expression expression) {
        return expression.evaluate();
    }
}

double twentyTwo = Calculator::calculate("2 + 4 * 5");

// This should be the same as the above calculation, since
// this is the AST of expressions that should be built by the
// lexer/parser
double twentyTwoAsWell = Calculator.calculate(new AdditionExpression(
    new NumberExpression(2),
    new MultiplicationExpression(
        new NumberExpression(4),
        new NumberExpression(5)
    )
));
```

**Note**: Important things like operator precedence can be handled by the lexer/parser.

Comment: Why `BinaryExpression` but not `UnaryExpression`?

Comment: @Caleth Why not `TernaryExpression`? I did it to keep the example a bit shorter and because having an abstract class for `BinaryExpression` provides slightly more boilerplate reducing benefits than a `UnaryExpression` abstract class. But yes, could definitely create `UnaryExpression` abstract class. Either way, these abstract classes are just for the reduction of boilerplate, the only thing that matters is the interface.